# Change background color of a specific tab in android tabs swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is my onCreate of my main activity

```
private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabHost tabHost;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "1", "2", "3" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // Initialization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFFFF0000));
        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        Log.d("miau", String.valueOf(tabHost));


        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

I need that every tab have a different color. Any pointer? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the ImageView for the particular Tab in the corresponding xml. And then give that image view Width and Height "MatchParent". And set the backgroung color for that Imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try to use the setCustomView(View v) method when you're adding a tab.

So like:

```
//...code

 for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this).setCustomView(myView);
        }

//...more code...
```

and then make your custom view (myView) just be a plain view with whatever color you want. I'm assuming you don't have a bunch of tabs. If you do then you may want to make a view, then randomly assign it a color on the fly. So have a large array of colors and then in your for loop assign myView a color and then set that view to your tab.

I'm not sure how this will affect the text of the tab though, but if it does you could add a textview to you custom view and then add the titles that way.

A more complicated version would be to make your own custom tab class and override everything that way.